# In GStreamer I've used 's3src' to get an mp4 from Amazon S3 to my computer. Why has the file size changed?

Tags: amazon-s3, gstreamer

https://github.com/ford-prefect/gst-plugin-s3

I've tried to use many different elements and combinations of elements in the command.

```
milanlakhani@ct-lt-966:~/GStreamer$ gst-launch-1.0 s3src uri=s3://eu-west-2/megaducket/youtube.mp4 ! rmdemux ! typefind ! decodebin ! queue ! filesink location=youtube_out9.mp4 name = youtube-out
```

Answer (score 0):

You are decoding the video data from the original file and store the result locally. This uncompressed data is much larger than the original file.

If you intended to just transfer the file from S3 you should not decode it in the process. The project's manual on GitHub actually has an example on how to transfer files:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 \
    s3src uri=s3://ap-south-1/my-bucket/my-object-key/which-can-have-slashes?version=my-optional-version ! filesink name=my-object.out
```